# the toggle method which is used to change theme of the ui isnt working?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I have defined my scss variables and my requirement is that when I click on toggle button the theme  of the entire page should change.

For this purpose I have defined toggletheme() as:

```
document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
```

But this is not working due to some reason.

Have defined dark theme as in scss:

```
//Dark Theme

$dark-chart-header: rgba(51,51,51,1);
$gray-2: rgba(32,32,32,1);
$light-gray-2: rgba(65,65,65,1);
$dark-gray-2: rgba(15,15,15,1);
$black: rgba(0,0,0,1);
$purple: rgba(80,7,120,1);
$graytext: rgba(201,201,201,1);
$lightgraytext: rgba(220,220,220,1);

$green: rgba(99,204,96,1);
$red: rgba(241,108,99,1);
$grayborder: rgba(209,209,209,0.2);
$darktext: rgba(51,51,51,1);


$no-padding: 0;
$no-margin: 0;
$no-border: none;


$tiny-font: 0.5em;
$xs-font: 0.6em;
$small-font: 0.7em;
$normal-font: 0.8em;
$normal-font-2: 0.9em;
$large-font: 1em;


$fluid: 100%;


$hide: none;
$show: inline-block;
```

this is all in Header Component which, in turn, has been embedded in app component.

Any help?

Comment: What is the relation between toggle class and above css ? Please explain

Comment: @Priyanka when the toggle method is executed it is suppose to add the dark theme css class to all the other variables.

Comment: Correct, that is the expectation. But the code you shared does not doing that. There is no logic I can find. You have to add some logic first. Even then if it's not worked people here can help you to solve that. What you have here are two separate codes, different css and different js.  There is no relation in between those.  I may misunderstand something, you can attach codepen link in that case.

Comment: I might be wrong but I understand all this scss code is nested in a `.dark-theme` style

Comment: https://codepen.io/ananyaneogi/pen/zXZyMP Hope this will help you. If you want to figure out issue in your code please provide the codepen link.

Comment: @RIni are you using angular or angularjs?

Comment: i am using angular

Comment: perhaps you could provide a stackblitz with a minimal example of the problem. With this toggle button, the scss...

Answer (score 0):

I would try by injecting the global document:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

And then using this injected property:

```
this.document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
```

I always try to use Renderer2 to access the dom but since you want to change a class of the body itself I would try this way.

And make sure all this scss of the dark-theme are inside:

```
.dark-theme {
   ...
}
```

in the global styles scss